# gwt searches jars in the wrong folder

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, path

I have just update to the last version of gwt, and then I start getting path errors.
22 jars file are supposed to be in the folder: 
    ~/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9/some_other_stuff

But i don't have this folder, I have all my jars file in
    ~/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.1/some_other_stuff

How can I change the main folder of the jars file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GWT SDK` linked in your application.

- Go To -> Project properties -> Google -> Web Toolkit
- Click on Configure SDK
- Now add or change the installed GWT SDK with version 1.9.1 as mentioned by you
- remove last added version 1.8.9

[image]

If still you are getting error then clean the project by removing all gwt-cache, compiled JavaScript files, deploy folder from war etc.